# composer runtime install error card not found peerAdmin

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I was following [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html) tutorial fine until I got an error

> Error: Card not found: PeerAdmin@hlfv1

at below command :

```
 composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName tutorial-network
```

The tutorial says that usually a peerAdmin identity has to be made but that they have already made one.

Answer (score 7):

For this tutorial you will have already followed the [instructions](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html) to set up your development environment.  There are some scripts to start the Fabric:

```
downloadFabric.sh
startFabric.sh
createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

If you run that last script it should solve your problem.

You can run `composer card list` to verify that you have the PeerAdmin card.

After further testing ...

I would say that either there is an existing card that can't be deleted for some reason, or else you do not have access to create the folder `~/.composer`.

I would suggest using this command to check if the folder exists `ls ~/.composer` and if it does, then `rm -rf ~/.composer` to remove it and all its contents.  Now create a new empty folder `mkdir ~/.composer` and rerun the script to create the Peer Admin card `createPeerAdminCard.sh` from the fabric-tools folder.

Comment: I followed the steps and the PeerAdmin@h1fv1.card was generated in the folder    /tmp/  but it still gives me  Error:     Card not found: PeerAdmin@h1fv1  when I run  composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName tutorial-network

Comment: What version of Composer are you running? ( composer -v )  If you are using v0.17.x then be sure to "export FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv11" before running these start and createPeerAdmin scripts.

Comment: I'm running v0.16.4. Should I run stopFabric.sh then do the export command?

Comment: no - only if you are on v0.17.*  - if you are using v0.16.4 the environment variable should NOT be set (you could use echo $FABRIC_VERSION to check it isn't.)

Answer (score 1):

Please use following two steps:

```
$composer network install -a test-bank@0.0.1.bna -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1
$composer network start --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --file networkadmin.card --networkName test-bank --networkVersion 0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

please try to use sudo as a prefix. below is the sample

- `sudo ./createPeerAdminCard.sh`
- `sudo composer card list --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1`
- "`sudo composer network deploy -a ../../Downloads/my-basic-sample.bna -A admin -S adminpw -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -f networkadmin.card`".

I was facing the same issue and using sudo as a prefix fixed it.

Comment: I ran it from "fabric-dev-servers" directory.

Answer (score 0):

i know that my answer is a bit late, but since i came across the same issue, here is what i did to solve it:

1. execute: `composer card list` to see what cards are already available.
2. If PeerAdmin card already exists, i would recommend you execute `~/fabric-tools/stopFabric.sh` followed by `~/fabric-tools/teardownFabric.sh` just make sure that you have removed all instances of the old PeerAdmin card
3. execute: `~/fabric-tools./createPeerAdminCard.sh` to create a brand new PeerAdmin card. execute step 1 to see if the card was created successfully
4. execute `~/fabric-tools./startFabric.sh` to start the Hyperledger Fabric services
5. now try to execute the above command and the issue should be fixed.